# how to use knockoutjs data binding with winjs datepicker

Tags: knockout.js, winjs

I created a DataPicker control using the following code.

```
<div id="date" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.DatePicker"></div>
```

I would like to use knockout to bind to the 3 select lists that get generated from WinJS.  Is there a way to use knockout declarative data binding to bind to the generated select lists?

Comment: Do you want to use knockout to set the date the picker is displaying, or do you want to use binding to actually populate the contents of the selects? Two rather different answers.

Comment: @ChrisTavares I am trying bind the date that the picker is displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ko.bindingHandlers['winjsDatePicker'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            options = allBindings['winjsDatePickerOptions'] || {};
        options['current'] = value;

        // Flatten the options for DatePicker
        var dpOptions = {};
        ko.utils.arrayForEach([
            'calendar', 'current', 'datePattern', 'disabled', 'element',
            'maxYear', 'minYear', 'monthPattern', 'yearPattern'
        ], function (prop) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                dpOptions[prop] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options[prop]);
            }
        });

        // Use jQuery to store the value-observable with the element
        $(element).data('winjsDatePickerCurrent', value);

        // Create the DatePicker, and pass it the options
        var dp = new WinJS.UI.DatePicker(element, dpOptions);

        // Wire up the onchange event
        dp.addEventListener("change", function() {
            var value = $(element).data('winjsDatePickerCurrent');
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
                value(dp.current);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var dp = element.winControl,
            value = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            options = allBindings['winjsDatePickerOptions'] || {};
        options['current'] = value;

        // Update the value-observable
        $(element).data('winjsDatePickerCurrent', value);

        // Update any properties
        ko.utils.arrayForEach([
            'calendar', 'current', 'datePattern', 'disabled', 'element',
            'maxYear', 'minYear', 'monthPattern', 'yearPattern'
        ], function (prop) {
            if (options[prop] !== undefined) {
                dp[prop] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options[prop]);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<div data-bind="winjsDatePicker: date"></div>​
<div data-bind="winjsDatePicker: date, winjsDatePickerOptions: { minYear: 2012 }"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/rs8Cd/

Answer (score 1):

I would probably look into a custom binding. You could still probably use declarative markup for your DatePicker, but it may be easier to instantiate your DatePicker inside the custom binding.

Note: I haven't had a chance to test this, but it may point you in the right direction. Also, I think in WinJS world, they'd prefer you to do `data-win-bind="winControl.current: yourprop"` but if you want to use KO, there's probably a way.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.winDatePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var currentDate = valueAccessor() || {};

        // In order for this to be true, you would had to call WinJS.UI.processAll() and *then* ko.applyBindings()
        if (element.winControl) {
            element.winControl.current = currentDate;
        }

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var currentDate = valueAccessor() || {};

        if (element.winControl) {
            element.winControl.current = currentDate;
        }
    }
};

/// <div data-bind="winDatePicker: myObservable" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.DatePicker" />
```

You could take a look at this gist I made. No warranties, though! You'd need to call `WinJS.Binding.processAll` before using this: https://gist.github.com/4183235